# Trouble disabling the Print Screen, Copy/Paste and right-click functionalities using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulties in implementing a JavaScript code to disable the Copy/Paste, Print Screen and right-click (context menu) using JavaScript and jQuery.

The problem is that if I comment out the code block of jQuery involving disabling the copy paste and the right click functionalities, the Print Screen functionality does not get disabled (I've tested out by pasting in MS Paint).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Disable Print Screen Demo</title>
<style>
    .container {
        background-color: lightblue;
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 390px;
        padding: 50px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }
</style>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Disable Print Screen Demo</h1>
    <hr />
    <p>
        Try to press the <b>"PrintScreen/SysRq"</b> key on your keyboard. 
    The user will get an alert that PrintScreen is Disabled and the content 
    will not be copied to the clipboard. 
    </p>
    </div>

<script>

// Disable Mouse Right Click
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("contextmenu", function(e){
        return false;
    });
});

// Disable PrintScreen (Screenshot)
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (keyCode == 44) {
        stopPrntScr();
        alert("Print Screen is Disabled!");
    }
});

function stopPrntScr() {
    var inpFld = document.createElement("input");
    inpFld.setAttribute("value", ".");
    inpFld.setAttribute("width", "0");
    inpFld.style.height = "0px";
    inpFld.style.width = "0px";
    inpFld.style.border = "0px";
    document.body.appendChild(inpFld);
    inpFld.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    inpFld.remove(inpFld);


    // Disable Cut Copy Paste
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').bind('cut copy paste', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you trying in? Are you pressing printscreen while focused in the browser window? If not, the event might not be firing at all.

Comment: @EricWu I'm trying it on Google Chrome. And yes, I'm pressing the printscreen key while focused on the browser window.

Comment: And is the event being fired? Did you try debugging to see what happens?

Comment: @EricWu No, I didn't tried to debug the code. I don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehtab, [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) is a comprehensive tutorial on how to debug js on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS instead of javascript, this will prevent selecting text in the browser.

```
<body class="noselect">
      your content goes here...
</body>

    <style>
        .noselect {
            -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
            -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
            -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
            -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                      supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
        }
    </style>
```